# Mouse jumps between using touchscreen and touchpad

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, asus, touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit on an ASUS VivoBook x202e for reference.

The laptop I got has a touchscreen (which I'm liking so far). One annoyance I noticed in Ubuntu, however, is that switching between using the touch screen vs the mouse causes the cursor to jump. At first I thought it might be remembering the mouse position for each device separately (e.g. when I touch the screen the cursor moves from point A to B, but then using the touchpad would cause it to return to A first before moving) but this is not the case.

What it actually seems to do is move down and to the right a bit when switching back to the touchpad after touching the screen somewhere. These seems pretty consistent anywhere on the screen.

I haven't been able to find any other mention of this. Any ideas what might be going on?

Edit: For reference, the following is the xinput list output for the pointing devices. The Elantech is the touchpad and the maXTouch is the screen.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Edit: This is kind of old, but I'll just mention at least with 14.10 I do not see this issue anymore. This required no effort on my part (except updating I suppose).

Comment: What mouse are you using?

Comment: @Private: I updated the question with the devices. Let me know if there's something else that would be helpful.

Comment: It may be related to the way you remove your finger (top left part of the pad of your finger first, causing the cursor to jump because the way you remove your finger doesn't register to you...)

Comment: @CallmeV: That doesn't seem to be the problem. Besides the fact that it doesn't jump after releasing pressure from the screen (only after then touching the touchpad), it doesn't seem to matter which direction I remove my finger or even if I give it some momentum first (e.g. releasing as I am moving my finger up and to the left). I think it's a problem with how the input device is handled, perhaps a driver issue? There's another noticeable artifact if I use a second output device: the screen touch locations are way off.

Comment: Touch screen are fairly new and there are sometimes bugs. Sounds as if an update / upgrade fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an "answer" per-se, but I don't get this issue using 14.10. At some point the issue must have been fixed. I'm not sure if it's fixed in 12.10 though.

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong if I guess at the moment of time you were referring at the second paragraph:

> At first I thought it might be remembering the mouse position for each device separately [...]

You were using Unity but then you changed to Gnome and thus changed your mind about the behaviour?

I also own a touchscreen laptop and I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 x64. Using Unity I can leave the mouse in a specific point, let's call it point A, then tap or drag on the screen in a completely different and random point in the screen and no matter what when I move my mouse (or trackpad) the pointer will begin it's movement from A.

However while using Gnome (3.6.2) the behaviour gets buggy. If I leave the pointer at A using the mouse/touchpad, then tap/drag in the screen to a final point B and then get to the mouse again the pointer will most of the times jump from B to a lower-right position as you described and in some cases it will start from A as in Unity.

I heard Canonical updated the touchscreen drivers in Ubuntu 12.10 and I guess they updated their desktop environment to suit these updates too. For me when I want to use the touchcreen I load Unity as in Gnome is mostly useless.

Cheers.

Comment: No, I still used Unity. Initially I didn't notice that it jumped by the same amount in the same direction each time so my first guess was that it might be remembering different locations for the different devices. I realized that not to be the case though.